# Decarte's type rule to estimate maximum number of complex roots of polynomial:

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a rule to determine maximum number of complex roots of given polynomial ?

By Decarte's sign rule we can determine minimum number of complex roots of given polynomial.

Comment: Decarte $\to$ Descartes

Comment: I do not think that this can be done with an easy rule. By the way : Are all the coefficients real ?

Comment: @Peter we can consider the case of real coefficients